# Filling vector with primes in a certain way

Tags: c++, vector, primes

I was asked to fill a given vector with prime numbers, I can't use any other vectors, arrays or collections. I've come up with something like this, but it doesn't work properly and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int n){                           
    if (n<=1){return false;}
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
        if (n % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;}

int fillWithPrimesVec(vector<int>& vec){
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<INT_MAX; j++){
            if (isPrime(j)){
                vec.push_back(j);}
            else{continue;}
            }
        }

    return vec[0];
}

int main(){

int c[15];
size_t szc = sizeof(c)/sizeof(*c);
vector<int> d(szc,0);

cout << fillWithPrimesVec(d);

return 0;
}
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Looks like a basic debugging scenario. It's definitely putting primes where you told it to.

Comment: 1. What way were you told to fill the vector with primes? 2. How is the vector currently being filled with primes?

Comment: There is no specified way of filling the vector with primes, this is what I've come up with. I thought that vec.push_back() fills vector with given argument, am I wrong? Those need to be ascending primes. I'm not that familliar with c++, thats where my question comes from.

Comment: "There is no specified way of filling the vector with primes" sorry I wasn't clear. I meant, "What pattern of prime numbers must be in the vector when you're done." Your original point of "I've been told to fill a vector with primes" could just be you filling it with the number 3 over and over. Thank you for the clarification, please add that into your question body.

Comment: You first resize the vector and then push_back to it. That's probably not what you meant to do.

Comment: First look at [std::vector constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), constructor number 3, to see which constructor you're using. Then look at [std::vector::push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to see what's happening to your vector.

Comment: Your `isPrime` function is hugely inefficient. First of all; you only need to test up to the square root of the number you are given. And even that (while a big improvement) is not the best you can do. Look up, for example [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and there are *even better* primality tests out there.

Comment: I don't think the efficiency of isPrime is the big concern here. But if it where, wouldn't it be nice if it had access to a list of prime numbers to test with?

Comment: "I was asked to fill a given vector with prime numbers" - fill it with `3`. `3` is a prime number, so filling your vector with it fulfills the requirement. 

Comment: If the user gets one `vector` and is allowed to use no arrays, etc.. It's hard to implement any of the primality sieves. I suppose there's some recursive template voodoo they could use, but that's because there ALWAYS seems to be some template voodoo that does the job.

Comment: Actually, Jesper Juhl's suggestion is a good one. Your prime numbers are good, but you seem to be unable to simply put N numbers in an array and print them. Do THAT and the rest will work.

Comment: @KennyOstrom `vec` could serve double duty as the sieve and the container of the results, but I don't think the instructor would approve.

Comment: Improvements: 2,3 then only test odd numbers, i +=2, once you've shown one number, i, is prime you can then start testing for the next from i+2

Comment: They need to put numbers in a vector, and print them. Quit fixing the part that already works!